# Webservice in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I make a webservice in ruby that interact with ruby web application.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to give us a bit more to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple stupid web service you can't go past Sinatra

http://www.sinatrarb.com/

The cannonical example.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
    "Hello World!"
end
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

You have not given us a lot to go on here however it is likely that you are interested in one or more of the following. Try googling them to see which one will do what you want

- ActiveResource
- ActionWebService
- Savon/Handsoap